# Area under a curve in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, area

Problem:

I have a two separated list of values, X={x1,x2....x2059} and Y={Y1,Y2....Y2059}. Using the Mathematica function "Transpose" i can obtain a new list Z = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{x2059,y2059}}. Using ListLinePlot[Z] i made the plot. 
Now, the problem is: How i can calculate the area under the plotted curve. I can't use NIntegrate, or Integrate. Can I use the interpolation function? how? 
Even using the Trapezoidal Rule (implemente by me) i didn't obtain a good resul.

The data comes from an Load-deformation plot. This means that for the first half part of the data, the curve growth. From the second part of data the curve come back to zero (close to zero). In particular, X = deformation and Y=Load.

Answer (score 4):

```
(*create a simulation for your points*)
npts = 2058;
x = Sort@RandomReal[100, npts];
y = Join[Sort@RandomReal[100, npts/2], Reverse@Sort@RandomReal[100, npts/2]];
f = Interpolation[Transpose@{x, y}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

(*Plot and Integrate*)
Plot[f[t], {t, Min@x, Max@x}, Filling -> Axis]
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, Min@x, Max@x}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

answer:

```
(* 5006.01 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I tried to use your code but with my data doesen't work. I asked this question just because i've implemented a similar code always without solution. The problem it's in the interpolation function.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I tried to use your code but with my data doesen't work. I asked this question just because i've implemented a similar code always without solution. The problem it's in the interpolation function. I would like also to ask also another question. Instead of the total area under the curve, how i can obtain a list like this: A = {area1, area2,area3..}, where every area(i) is the area of a single element of the curve (e.g. if my x is 2059 elements, i can take area1 = area(x3-x1),area1 = area(x3-x2)..."Like a trapezoidal rule" Thank's